# PHP - Implicit type handling not working?

Tags: php, php-5.6

I'm importing an Excel file.

The file has mixed data types - item code, currency values, dates.

The item codes can have leading zeroes, so I'm using:

```
$objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->toArray('', false, true, false);
```

As you would expect, this is retaining the leading zeroes, and is also retaining number formatting: 12,345.00

The problem is that we need certain numbers in float format, to perform operations on them.

For some reason, PHP isn't performing implicit type conversion.

e.g.:

```
$value = "21,356.00";
$newvalue =  $value * 2;
```

This returns: 42.  I expected it to return 42712.00.

Why is this happening?

With the excel file, we only know which column contains the item codes.  The other columns can be anything, so I can't just parse float across them all.  We identify them by the header row in the file.

Ideally we need to implicit type conversion to work.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

If you try to use a string like "22,345.43" as a float in PHP, it will discard everything behind the first comma and convert it to a 22. If you try to use a currency formatted string like "$ 22,234.45" it will be converted to 0.

To avoid this, you need this function:
http://php.net/manual/es/function.floatval.php#114486

Note: **you don't need floatval**, you need to use **toFloat($num)** in the first "user-contributed" note.

That function takes a string with any formatted number on it, detects the last dot or comma, and uses that last separator to parse the number. The function also ignores everything but digits, so it's useful to remove currencies and thousands separators.

It's not a native PHP function so you will have to include that function in your code to be able to use it.